# NSImage rotation in NSView is not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I am trying to rotate an NSImage inside a NSView., First I will show you what I have done so far.

---

### Image :

---

[image]

---

### Header file

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject {
    CALayer *syncFirst;
}

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *nsview;

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
- (CGImageRef) convertToCGImageFromNasImage:(NSImage *) image;

@end
```

---

### Implementation file, only related methods

---

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    
    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"SyncRing.png"];
    //init layer
    syncFirst = [CALayer layer];
    
    //animatated content size init
    syncFirst.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    syncFirst.position = CGPointMake(10, 10);
    syncFirst.contents = (id)[self convertToCGImageFromNasImage:image];

    [nsview.layer addSublayer:syncFirst];
}

 /*To convert NSImage in CGImage*/

- (CGImageRef) convertToCGImageFromNasImage:(NSImage *) image {
     NSData* cocoaData = [NSBitmapImageRep TIFFRepresentationOfImageRepsInArray: [image representations]];
     CFDataRef carbonData = (__bridge CFDataRef)cocoaData;
     CGImageSourceRef imageSourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(carbonData, NULL);
     CGImageRef myCGImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSourceRef, 0, NULL);
     return myCGImage;
}

/*When button click animate the image*/

- (IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2 * M_PI) * 1];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [syncFirst addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotateAnimation"];
}
```

---

### Question :

---

Basically I am trying to rotate this image after click a button. The code I am trying is not 100% implementation but learnt from several different places including Apple documentation. Now, it is obvious that I am doing some naive mistake but logically my code seems correct to me. It would be great if someone can point out my mistake and give me understanding about why it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any future visitors, The code works perfectly and you may use it if you want except make sure before you add layer inside nsview we have to set that nsview wants layer.

so, the changes will be...

---

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"SyncRing.png"];
    //init layer
    syncFirst = [CALayer layer];

    //animatated content size init
    syncFirst.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    syncFirst.position = CGPointMake(10, 10);
    syncFirst.contents = (id)[self convertToCGImageFromNasImage:image];
    
    /*HERE SETWANTSLAYER TO TRUE IN ORDER TO FIX*/
    [nsview setWantsLayer:YES];

    [nsview.layer addSublayer:syncFirst];
}
```

---

### Before using this code

Please refer to the discussion in comment. There are some useful tips, Which I have overlooked while solving my problem. Credit goes to - [Peter Hosey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30461/peter-hosey)

Comment: Don't forget to set `nsview`'s `layer` to a layer you created first. You're not supposed to manipulate the AppKit-created layer of a layer-backed view. If you want to add your own sublayers, you must create your own layer for the view and make it a layer-hosting view. See the documentation for `setWantsLayer:` for details: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setWantsLayer:

Comment: @PeterHosey, I checked the sample code of Apple but it saves the old content view so when the animation is finished they can clean up and set everything as it use to be. But in my case the animation goes forever. and one more thing, so if I want to do it in a right way I must create a layer as a hostingLayer for animation add it inside nsview and then add my animation layer into hostingLayer. am I right?

Comment: Yes, you must create your own layer, hand it to the view, and tell the view it wants layer. I don't think it matters whether you add the sublayer before or after passing the root layer to the view. (Note that “hostingLayer” doesn't make sense: the view hosts the layer, not the other way around.)

Comment: Great, Thank you very much for enlightenment