# Create animation for Circle Progress Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make a progress arc using UIBezierPath that will go all around in a complete circle and finish animating once it lands in the correct progress. So essentially it needs to do a full 360 deg and then go however far it needs to go to meet its progress. As of now I can only animate it to go to its ending angle like so:

```
CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = 2.0; // "animate over 10 seconds or so.."
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;  // Animate only once..

    // Animate from no part of the stroke being drawn to the entire stroke being drawn
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

    // Experiment with timing to get the appearence to look the way you want
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    // Add the animation to the circle
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
        [progressArc addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
    });
```

How can I make my arc animate in such a way where it goes all the way around and stops at the correct end angle?

Comment: "So essentially it needs to do a full 360 deg and then go however far it needs to go to meet its progress" But how will you be able to _see_ that it does this? If, say, a red circle draws itself into a full circle and then _keeps going_, you are merely adding more red where there is already red. It won't be possible to _see_ anything more than the single full circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a layer animate a rotation by an arbitrary amount (including > 360 degrees) by creating a `CAValueFunction`. Check my second answer on [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826288/how-do-i-achieve-continuous-rotation-of-an-nsimage-inside-nsimageview). The code in that thread is in Objective-C, which looks like what you want. For anyone else reading this thread who needs Swift code, post a comment and I'll try to find the time to create a Swift example.

Comment: Rotating a view is not at all the same as animating a shape layer's `strokeEnd`.

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice that you were using strokeEnd.